# How to handle joins between huge tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization, join, query-optimization

I have two tables:
urls (table with indexed pages, host is indexed column, 30 mln rows)
hosts (table with information about hosts, host is indexed column, 1mln rows)

One of the most frequent SELECT in my application is:

```
SELECT urls.* FROM urls
JOIN hosts ON urls.host = hosts.host
WHERE urls.projects_id = ?
    AND hosts.is_spam IS NULL
ORDER by urls.id DESC, LIMIT ?
```

In projects which have more than 100 000 rows in urls table the query executes very slow.

Since the tables has grown the query is execution slower and slower. I've read a lot about NoSQL databases (like MongoDB) which are designed to handle so big tables but changing my database from PgSQL to MongoDB is for me big issue. Right now i would like try to optimize PgSQL solution. Do you have any advice for? What should i do?

Comment: 100k rows is really not "huge" at all.

Comment: Please run an `explain analyze` on a sample of your query and add the result in your question, along with the list of indexes you have on the `hosts` and `urls` tables. 100k rows is definitely something pg should be able to handle without much issue unless it is really starving for ressource.

Comment: while optimization may improve things a bit, I would like to suggest some alternatives. I need to know a few things - why are you paginating (for display/reducing size of single read/just for testing)? Would it be unacceptable to receive less rows than what the LIMIT clause specifies?

Comment: is it possible that there is no record in hosts table corresponding to a record in urls table?

Comment: When doing the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` suggested by @Lepidosteus , use http://explain.depesz.com/ . It'll be much more readable and you can just post a link that way.

Please also show the *exact table definitions* in use. The output of `\d tablename` from psql would be fine, or the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index on the `hosts.host` column (primarily in the `hosts` table, this matters), and a composite index on `urls.projects_id, urls.id`, run `ANALYZE` statement to update all statistics and observe subsecond performance regardless of spam percentage.

A slightly different advice would apply if almost everything is always spam and if the "projects", whatever they are, are few in number and and very big each.

Explanation: update of statistics makes it possible for the optimizer to recognize that the `urls` and `hosts` tables are both quite big (well, you didn't show us schema, so we don't know your row sizes).  The composite index starting with `projects.id` will hopefully<sup>1</sup> rule out most of the `urls` content, and its second component will immediately feed the rest of `urls` in the desired order, so it is quite likely that an index scan of `urls` will be the basis for the query plan chosen by the planner.  It is then essential to have an index on `hosts.host` to make the hosts lookups efficient; the majority of this big table will never be accessed at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>)  Here is where we assume that the `projects_id` is reasonably selective (that it is not the same value throughout the whole table).

Answer (score 2):

This query should be fast in combination with the provided indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX hosts_host_idx ON hosts (host)
WHERE is_spam IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX urls_projects_id_idx ON urls (projects_id, id DESC);

SELECT *
FROM   urls u
WHERE  u.projects_id = ?
AND    EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   hosts h USING (host)
    WHERE  h.is_spam IS NULL
    )
ORDER  BY urls.id DESC
LIMIT  ?;
```

The indexes are the more important ingredient. The JOIN syntax as you have it may be just as fast. Note that the first index is a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) and the second is a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) with `DESC` order on the second column.

It much depends on specifics of your data distribution, you will have to test (as always) with EXPLAIN ANALYZE to find out about performance and whether the indexes are used.

[General advice about performance optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) applies, too. You know the drill.